# How to not convert double to int C#?

Tags: c#

Ok people let me try to clear the last itme. I have an object a and I want to check if its value is double, int or string.

For eg: - 
if object a = "12.3" or a = 12.3, it should be able to convert to double and throw while converting to int.
if object a = "12" or a = 12 or a = 12.0, it should be able to convert to int and throw while converting to double.

if object a="apple" it should throw for both double and int.

Hope I am clear this time. But Timwi's solution actually solved the problem for me. :-)

Comment: Why do you need to throw an exception?

Comment: If you don't want to convert a double to an int, just don't do it. Are you saying you want to allow it if it's already an exact integer value (e.g. 12.0), but not otherwise?

Comment: Presumably `a` is an `object`, thus making your code example a bit inapplicable?

Comment: @romkyns a is a double in the example. var is pre-compilation implicit typing, but it isn't object. And even if casted to object, wills till work because ToInt32 has overload that accepts object.

Comment: @YoryeNathan If that's the case then the question is meaningless, because the answer is "well don't convert, just throw". So I have to assume the OP meant something else.

Comment: Yes, he wants to convert to int, but throw if the number was rounded.

Comment: @YoryeNathan that is not specified in the question; you seem to be guessing just like all of us here.

Comment: what about checking the runtime type of a with is operator and throwing the exc yourself if is not int?

Comment: @romkyns True, but `a` is not `object` in any case. `var` is translated to `double` in this case. Check it yourself. Hover over the `var` keyword.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Of course `var` stands for `double` here :) But given how badly this question is written, however, I was wondering whether the code supplied was not quite what the OP actually wanted to ask.

Comment: @romkyns Yes, and I see that others started downvoting the question as well, realizing they are fighting over ambiguity.

Comment: @YoryeNathan What do you know, I was actually correct about `object`.... :)

Comment: After the edit, it is clear that you should use the `is` operator.

Comment: Even with the clarification the question is still far too unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a double and you want to convert it to int if it’s an integer and otherwise throw. Is this what you want?

```
public static int ToInt32(double val)
{
    if (val % 1 != 0)
        throw new FormatException("The value is not an integer.");
    return Convert.ToInt32(val);
}
```

Comment: `val % 1 != 0` This will fail a lot more than you think.

Comment: @leppie: Your comment would probably be more helpful if you gave an example of a way in which it fails?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `a` is of type `object` in your example, and the real code is a bit like this:

```
int myToInt(object a)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(a);
}
```

but you want this to throw if `a` is an integer. How about this then:

```
int myToInt(object a)
{
    if (a is double)
        throw new ArgumentException("a", "Must not be a double");
    return Convert.ToInt32(a);
}
```

Comment: Edit the question so I can undo it :P

Comment: So he wants to EXCLUDE double? Oh well, why not just explaining the `is` operator and let him do what he wants?

Comment: @YoryeNathan I've thought about this some more and I'm once again not sure quite what he wants, for example, if the string is "12.5", should it throw or not. I'll leave that to others though...

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 12.34;
int c = Int32.Parse(a.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer,
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will throw an exception if the string representation of the number is not a integer. The documentation for it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz.aspx).

Comment: No, that *won't* throw an exception - you're using `Int32.TryParse`. If you used `Int32.Parse` it would throw...

Comment: yea mental lapse. updated to correct method and documentation

Comment: Edited again partly so I could undo my downvote, and partly to fix the use of the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're all totally guessing what the OP wants here, I'll have another go. Assuming you want a method that throws if and only if the value was truncated, try something like this:

```
int MyToInt32(double value)
{
    if (value != Math.Floor(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("value", "The value must not have a fractional part");
    return (int) value;
}
```

But this is probably a rather bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First [Convert.Int32(double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx) does not truncate the value taking the integer part and excluding the decimal part. Infact it returns the rounded value.

> value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is
>   halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that
>   is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Casting will truncate the value and will take the integer part and discard the decimal part.

For your question

> Is there a custom c# method by which I will be able to throw format
>   exception or something when I try to convert double to int. ??

`Convert.ToInt32` would throw an exception if the value passed to it is not a valid double value. e.g.

```
 var val = "12.54A";
 int iVal = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

Whereas if you try to cast it using int iVal = (int) val; will give you compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using mathematics?
You could try to add some value to the double to make sure it's bigger (or smaller) than an int can be.
then try to convert (which will return an error) and the the opposite mathematical function.

Still dunno why you want to throw an error ...
Double -> int will work, if the variable is in between the int-borders

Answer (score 0):

What about using is

```
if( x is int )
{
    // convert here
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Not an int");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a cast

```
var a = 12.34
int integer = (int)a;
```

Comment: In what way does that answer the question? That will *not* throw an exception in your example - it'll just truncate the result to 12, just like the OP's `Convert.ToInt32` call.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, it throws exception only if the double is too big for the int.

Comment: No actually this will throw an invalid cast exception. It won't truncate because we try to cast a higher value to a lower value..